# Is there anywhere that you can buy Kosher non Glatt meat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, ashkenazi, product-recommendation

When you go shopping, it seems that they only offer Glatt Kosher. I would imagine non Glatt would be cheaper. Is there anywhere that someone who is not Makpid (It is an American post world war phenomenon to be Makpid) on Glatt that you can purchase **fresh** meat with a reliable Hashgacha?

Comment: Could it be that there is an established minhag now for shomrei mitzvos to be makpid (or was that decided for by the hashgacha companies)?

Comment: I suggest you not be like Marrie Antoinette and Just not eat meat

Comment: Anywhere ...where? In the U.S.? In North America? In Israel? In Europe? In the world?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated, most meat available in America today that is up to conventional kosher standards is also glatt.  From what I understand if I heard correctly from Rabbi Hershel Schachter, "glatt" was the excuse for creating a far superior standard of kosher in America than what had preceded it (e.g. requiring the slaughterpeople be Sabbath-observant).

When Rubashkin's was in business, Trader Joe's would carry some non-glatt meat that came from Rubashkin's plants; it had a shield-K kosher sign of a Rabbi Zeilingold. I was told from someone in the field that it was considered "reliable, though not glatt."  But that has since gone the way of Rubashkin's.

I believe all the kosher slaughter done in America today that is up to conventional standards is done under either the OU, Star-K, or cRC; and I think all of them require glatt.

Go to the United Kingdom and you can find meat under the London Shechita Authority (a joint venture of the London Beth Din, the Federation of Synagogues; and the Sephardic organization) available in "plain", "glatt", or "Beis Yosef glatt."  All are considered reliable (though many ultra-Orthodox in the UK instead go with the all-glatt Union of Hebrew Orthodox Congregations' "Kedassia" certified meat instead.)

Comment: Most meat sold in Israel is not glatt.

Answer (score 3):

[CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) about what's considered a reliable *hashgacha*, but Hebrew National is widely available, has *hashgacha* (I don't eat it, but, as I say, CYLOR), and isn't *glat*.

Comment: Hebrew National is not fresh meat, I am looking for fresh meat with a reliable Hashgacha that is not Glatt.

Comment: In Israel most meat not under Mehadrin is not glatt all Rabanut like Burger King and the like

Answer (score 1):

trader joes has non glatt meat. costco as hebrew national

Comment: That Trader Joe's meat has a Triangle-K, if I'm not mistaken. Check your local Orthodox rabbi whether that hechsher is considered to follow normative standards, other than glatt.

Comment: the kosher meat at trader joes is more expensive than most glatt kosher meat